# select list based on select query in apache zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

i am using apache zeppelin version 0.6.
i have the following  hive query

select certificate_name,count(*) from student_withdraw

now i want to have a where clause which is represented to the end user as a select list. the inner query is like below

select certificate_name,count(*) from student_withdraw where lecturer_name in (select distinct lecturer_name from student_withdraw)

now the default notation to have a select list is "${item=A,A|B|C}"

i tried to have it like below

%jdbc(hive)
select certificate_name,count(*) from student_withdraw where lecturer_name =  "${item=Null,select distinct lecturer_name from student_withdraw}" group by certificate_name

but cannot fetch the distinct lecturers in the select list. all is shown in the select list is the query.

how can i select the distinct lectures for the select list?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Assumption

Your scenario looks involving dynamic forms on **Zeppelin**. I can agree with your logic yet dynamic forms won't execute any SQL, or HiveQL, then pass the result as an option onto a page, merely exactly what you typed. 
I assume your installation of **Zeppelin** includes all interpreters, the table is a managed native table on **Hive**, and the selection of lecturers for end users is necessary.

### Solution

If the number of unique lecturer names is not much, like below 10, just typed them all manually in the `select form` of the query.

```
SELECT certificate_name, COUNT(*)
FROM student_withdraw
WHERE lecturer_name = ${item=nameA, nameA|nameB|nameC}
GROUP BY certificate_name
```

Otherwise, you may consider composing the string of the whole lecturer names first, then copying and pasting the outcome into the `select form` of the query.
Something like the following:

```
%pyspark
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hc = HiveContext(sc)
student_withdraw = hc.table("student_withdraw")
student_withdraw.registerTempTable("student_withdraw")
lecturer_list = student_withdraw.sql('SELECT DISTINCT lecturer_name FROM student_withdraw').rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect()
lecturer_names = '|'.join(lecturer_list)
print(lecturer_names)
```

```
%jdbc(hive)
SELECT certificate_name, COUNT(*)
FROM student_withdraw
/*the second argument in the select form is copied from the result of the previous execution*/
WHERE lecturer_name = ${item=nameA, nameA|nameB....|nameY|nameZ}
GROUP BY certificate_name
```

Comment: it gives the following error

>Traceback (most recent call last):
 > File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-7505688587607622782.py", line 344, in <module>
>    code = compile('\n'.join(final_code), '<stdin>', 'exec', >ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST, 1)
 > File "<stdin>", line 5
  >  lecturer_list = student_withdraw.sql('select distinct lecturer_name >from studentdb.student_withdraw').rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect()
                                                                                                                     >^
>SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: i use this code because i could'nt found any %pyspark interpreter in zeppelin  so i use %spark.pyspark

Comment: is your version of Zeppelin really 0.6.0? Different syntax for **pyspark** since 0.7.0. I used `%pyspark` according to the info presented from your question. If you have time, you could check   
[Spark Interpreter for Apache Zeppelin 0.6.0](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/interpreter/spark.html)
and [Spark Interpreter for Apache Zeppelin 0.7.0](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/interpreter/spark.html)

Comment: If you don't have *Spark* installed, either standalone or cluster mode, you could try the same logic as the first step on shell using *Hive* command. IF the selection of lecturers, or dynamic form, is necessary to be enabled.

Comment: i using zeppelin 0.7.0, spark interpreter is there, the only difference with the 0.7.0 documentation and my configuration is that that MASTER property of spark interpreter is null in my case. should i set it to local[*] as described in the docs?

Comment: actually i am using hortownworks hadoop distribution HDP, in which i have installed spark and spark2 which is shown up in my ambari server interface. there services are okay.

Comment: hive was very slow in performance, i replace my code to spark. can you tell me how can we rewrite the same code for spark as you mentioned in the %PAYSPARK section above?